# Vue JS 2: Stop lifecycle after beforeCreate

Tags: javascript, vue.js, lifecycle

Is there a way to stop rendering and execution of created() and mounted() in the beforeCreate method? Just calling $destroy() on the component will fire after created.

[image: vue js lifecycle]

Answer (score 3):

No.  There are other ways to prevent a component from rendering

#### `v-if`

Use `v-if` in the parent to conditionally render.

```
<child v-if="shouldRender"></child>
```

```js
data: () => ({
  shouldRender: false
})
```

#### `beforeRouteEnter`

If the component is a router page, you can prevent it from being created with the [`beforeRouteEnter`](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/navigation-guards.html#in-component-guards) navigation guard.

```
beforeRouteEnter (to, from, next) {
  if (something) {
    // Don't render the component, go somewhere else
    next({ path: '/somewhere' });  
  }
}
```